# Windows text editor for editing files hosted on remote linux server

Tags: windows, linux, text-editor

I am using a Windows-7 PC and I have to edit and save files which are stored on a Linux server which I usually access using PUTTY and edit them using Vi editor.

Vi editor is hard to use for me (as I am windows user).

**is there any editor by which I can connect to server and modify the files on the server and save it?**.

**Update:** I can use FTP because I can't install anything on the Linux server but I can install anything on the Windows PC. If the Editor has file browser it is added advantage.

Comment: You could mount the remote storage e.g. via [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sshfs) and then use any of your favorite Windows editors. Would that suit you? If not, you need to specify by which means that editor can access the files on the Linux machine (FTP?)

Comment: @Izzy i updated my question.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, an editor with a built-in FTP browser would be a fitting solution? Such as [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) with its *NppFTP* module?

Comment: wow it worked like charm and it has file browser also! Thanks!

Comment: I made it an answer then. Enjoy!

Comment: Vim is hard to use for *any* user who has not familiarized himself with it, and its concepts. Once you *do* actually *learn* that editor (and I mean *learning*, not just memorizing the most-often-used keystrokes), you'll find just what it is that makes people still use it. I'd recommend doing so.

Comment: Did you consider `emacs` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the perfect match for you is **[Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B),** which ships with an FTP file browser:

[image: NppFTP] [image: NppFTP config]
<sup>*Notepad++* with opened FTP browser / FTP config (source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656779/2533433); click images for larger variants)</sup>

For details on how to configure it, please follow up to our sister site's article [Notepad++ with Local and FTP synchronizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656779/2533433).

**Hot does this fit your requirements:**

- you can use a graphical editor on Windows as you're used to
- you can access the files located on the Linux machine via its built-in FTP browser
- it comes for free (oh, you didn't ask for that? I take donations if you insist ;)

And just in case: The Notepad++ homepage [can be found here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: thanks you saved me from  Vi editor headache. +1.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm using both – and which to prefer entirely depends on the situation. But I fully understand how you feel :)

Answer (score 2):

[**UltraEdit**](http://ultraedit.com/), a very powerful (!!) editor with "traditional" interface I've been using a lot before I switched to Vim.

- built-in SSH client
- file browser

It's available for Windows, MacOS, *and Linux*. Not free, but IMHO worth the money, and coming with a free trial so you can give it a test.

I personally rank it as the #2 editor after Vim on any platform.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend **[Atom](http://atom.io)** (the hackable text editor - from the people who brought you GitHub).

There are a couple of FTP packages for Atom, haven't tried them myself.

- [atom-ftp-editor](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ftp-editor)
- [Remote-FTP](https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp)
- [SFTP-Deployment](https://atom.io/packages/sftp-deployment)
- [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit)

More at https://atom.io/packages/search?q=ftp

Comment: Thanks @amedee for your answer, but Atom loads slow in windows when compared to Notepad++ and Sublime 3. Anyways +1

Comment: I don't know that, I use it on Linux. Sometimes I have the need to edit files on a headless server and I am not in the mood to use vi incantations. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Notepad++; we only have UltraEdit allowed at work, and it does the job and nicely and has built-in ftp. I've rebuilt the popup menu to the items I use most.

But, np++ abides by more standards, and I find more intuitive. I made UltraEdit into something useful for me after over a year of using, still find it clunky. np++ was slick out of the box.

eg "ctrl-w" toggles word wrap in UltraEdit; np++, it... well, closes the top window.

I find np++ deals w/ columnar data soooo much more flexibly than does UltraEdit; the latter is "modal," altho does perfunctory selection and copy out of mode.

I prefer the way that np++ does searches and replaces for multiline data more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try Far Manager
It is a console application with a powerful text editor, file browsing, and FTP support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As other people have noted, using the FTP capabilities of IDEs such as Notepad++ might work well for you.

Though, if you want a text editor which you can run on the Linux server through SSH with PUTTY, you might want to use nano. Nano generally comes by default on most Linux servers.

**Nano** is a command line-based text editor like vim, however, it is much easier for beginners to use than vim. It relies far less on keyboard commands and is much more intuitive to people who are used to more graphical-based text editors.

Answer (score 0):

[SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/) (free) is OK for this task: it has editor and FTP plugin [ported from Notepad++, so it has simiar UI].

To call ftp, show side panel (using icon on toolbar "arrow left") and call FTP tab, then create FTP account using FTP icon "gear".

[image: Synwrite]