# Free text editing tool specifically designed for remote editing

Tags: gratis, text-editor, remote-access

I'd like a full GUI text editing tool that transparently opens and saves files over ssh or sftp as a built-in feature. I tested remote-edit with Atom and opening files doesn't work. Additionally the documentation for the workflow (add host, open file, save file) is missing or nonexistent and none appears to exist on the internet.

All of this must be built into one program, no extra side setup such as sshfs or remote disk mounts. Additionally the remote editing must use a standard ssh or sftp server backend with no additional setup such as rmate. I shouldn't have to do any more setup than providing hostname/IP address and login info for ssh/sftp.

Comment: so which platform are you running it on? If it's Windows then it's a duplicate of [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/29792/3579)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it's for Mac/Linux/UNIX platforms although that should be obvious considering most people don't associate Windows with ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you already tried one for Atom, I will point out that there are several, and maybe you will like another one better.

The one I like best for Atom is [ftp-remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/ftp-remote-edit) (by h3imdall). I found it easy to set up (in fact it was the only one was able to figure out how to get working) and to me, using it is simple and transparent.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many features I love about `emacs`. The TRAMP mode allows transparent remote file access, including editing, directory browsing, running grep, doing compiles, and other stuff. TRAMP-specific info available at:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode

https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/